# How to login to systemd-based Linux if there are no /dev/tty[0-9]* devices?

Tags: linux, systemd, boot, logind

I am forced to use a kernel without virtual console support. There is only a `/dev/tty` device. As a userspace, I use the Debian testing distribution. In rescue mode, I checked that it is possible to start Xorg with the `-novtswitch` argument without `-vt*`, and it works. Please help me with systemd to set up at least a console login to `/dev/tty`. Or if it's real on `/dev/pts/*` (support is in the kernel). If you manage to configure gdm3, then this is generally very good.

Thank you.